# How to use Pusher send message client to client via javascript not work

Tags: javascript, pusher

How to use Pusher send message client to client via javascript

Cliente 1

```
var pusher = new Pusher('app_key','app_secret','app_id',{'encrypted' : true});
var channel = pusher.subscribe('private-test_channel');
channel.bind('pusher:subscription_succeeded', function() {
  var triggered = channel.trigger('client-my_event', { your: 'teste' });
});
```

Client 2

```
var pusher = new Pusher('2b4e6485993854028f56', {
  encrypted: true
});
var channel = pusher.subscribe('test_channel');
channel.bind('my_event', function(data) {
  console.log(data.message);
});
```

Status

Pusher : State changed : initialized -> connecting

Pusher : Connecting : {"transport":"ws","url":"ws://ws.pusherapp.com:80/app/acc5afdb4877ed77b190?protocol=7&client=js&version=3.0.0&flash=false"}

Pusher : State changed : connecting -> conectei

POST http://localhost/pusher/auth 404 (Not Found)

Pusher : Couldn't get auth info from your webapp : 404

page1.html:10 Pusher : Couldn't get auth info from your webapp : 404

page1.html:10 Pusher : No callbacks on private-test_channel for pusher:subscription_error

Answer (score -1):

You need to implement an authentication endpoint that is running on the path `pusher/auth` when you are using private channels. You can read more about how to do this in the [Pusher docs](https://pusher.com/docs/authenticating_users).

It looks like you are running this locally. In order that both clients can talk to the auth endpoint, you will need to host it on another machine. You could do this with something like Heroku.